# How do I make my GAE app publicly accessible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iam

I've got a GAE app that runs a publicly hosted dataset through a model via Flask, displaying the results. I successfully deployed it, and I can access & use it from the account that deployed it, but how do I make it publicly available? Right now from outside my account, I can access the app's index.html at its .appspot.com address, but when I press the app's run-the-model button, I'm taken to a login page instead of my model_result.html.

I've been trying to find an answer [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control), but am quickly getting out of my depth in terms of IAM terminology.

Comment: What url is your button sending you too and whats that route look look in your app.yaml and flask request hanlders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex pointed out- my app.yaml request handlers need to be set for the behavior I wanted: login: optional (not login: required). Thanks!